# How can I access 'key' and 'value' from an array in a for loop?

Tags: loop, array

How can I change the for loop below so that I can assign the array's "key" value as the "value" for each input instead of the array's "option" value as I'm now doing (I still want to echo the array's "option" value as the label)?

```
$myradiooptions = array("grid1" => "Grid View (default)", "list1" => "List View (1 column)", "list2" => "List View (2 column)" );

$options = array (
array( "name" => "My Theme Options","type" => "title"), array( "type" => "open"),

array(  "name" => "Category Layout",
     "desc" => "description goes here",
     "id" => "my_category_layout",
     "type" => "radio",
    "options" => $myradiooptions ),

    ...etc}

//switch, case "radio":
?>
<li class="section">
    <label class="left" for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
    <?php $count=1;foreach ($value['options'] as $option) { ?>
    <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $count; ?>" value="<?php echo $option; ?>" <?php checked($option, get_settings($value['id'])); ?>/><label style="color:#666; margin:0 20px 0 5px;" for="<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $option; ?></label>
  <?php $count++;} ?>
    <label class="description" style="margin-top:-5px;"><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></label>
</li>
<?php
break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly just change

```
<?php $count=1;foreach ($value['options'] as $key => $option) { ?>
```

and you can access the key from $key.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. I also had to change the checked to checked($key, get_settings($value['id'])); Thanks!